# MySQL - nested select queries running many time slower than sequential queries (on a large table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that I am having performance problems with that I do not understand.  When I try to debug and run the overall query as a sequence of separate subqueries they seem to perform reasonably well, given the volume of data.  When I combine them into a single nested query I get much much much longer execution times.

The main `ratings` table mentioned below is approx 30 million rows (4GB of disk space), with a couple of foreign keys (it's a many-to-many table linking users and items with a small amount of additional supplementary user specific item information - approx 13 fields and 30 bytes).

**Query 1** - approx 23s

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT fields FROM ratings WHERE (id >= 0 AND id < 10000) 
AND item_type = 1) AS t1;
```

**Query 1 saved to table** - approx 65s if I save the results to a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table SELECT fields FROM ratings WHERE (id >= 0 AND id < 10000) 
AND item_type = 1;
```

**Query 2** - approx 3s

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp_table WHERE id IN (SELECT id from item_stats WHERE 
ratings_count > 1000);
```

Bases on this I would expect a combined query to be approx 30s or so, and not more than approx 70s.

**Combined query (Query 1 + Query 2)** - indeterminate time (10s of minutes before I give up and cancel)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from (SELECT * FROM (SELECT fields FROM ratings WHERE (id >= 0 
AND id < 10000) AND item_type = 1) AS t1 WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT id FROM 
item_stats WHERE ratings_count > 1000)) as t2;
```

**Can anyone help explain this difference and guide me in creating a query that works?**  If I need to I can rely on the sequential queries (which would take approx 70s), but that is cumbersome and does not seem the right way to go.

I have tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` but this did not seem to make much difference.  The ID count from the `item_stats` table is about 2700 IDs.

It's using MySQL 8.0 on a laptop (16GB RAM, SSD).

**Response to suggestions / questions:**

Query 1

```
EXPLAIN select user_id, game_id, item_type_id, rating, plays, own, bgg_last_modified from collections where (user_id >= 0 and user_id < 10000) and item_type_id = 1;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | collections | NULL       | ALL  | user_id       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 32898400 |     1.31 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Query 2

```
EXPLAIN select * from temp_coll where game_id in (select game_id from games_ratings_stats where (ratings_count > 1000) or (ratings_count > 500 and ratings_avg >= 7.0));
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table               | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2>         | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    NULL |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | temp_coll           | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1674386 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | games_ratings_stats | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   81585 |    40.74 | Using where                                |
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Combined query

```
 EXPLAIN select * from (select user_id, game_id, item_type_id, rating, plays, own, bgg_last_modified from collections where (user_id >= 0 and user_id < 10000) and item_type_id = 1) as t1 where t1.game_id in (select game_id from games_ratings_stats where (ratings_count > 1000) or (ratings_count > 500 and ratings_avg >= 7.0));
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table               | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery3>         | NULL       | ALL  | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                |  NULL |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | collections         | NULL       | ref  | user_id,game_id | game_id | 5       | <subquery3>.game_id |   199 |     1.31 | Using where |
|  3 | MATERIALIZED | games_ratings_stats | NULL       | ALL  | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                | 81585 |    40.74 | Using where |
+----+--------------+---------------------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you set indexes? Did you use `EXPLAIN` to see what is happening with your queries?

Comment: Indexes exist for the main table. I've added the EXPLAIN output. Slightly different fields etc from original question as I sought to simplify (but same structure)!

Comment: As far as I can tell, your combined query can be simplified to this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings WHERE id >= 0 
AND id < 10000 AND item_type = 1 AND id IN (SELECT id FROM 
item_stats WHERE ratings_count > 1000)`. Your use of inner SELECTs causes large amounts of data to be processed.

Comment: Thanks Fred - I will take a look at that, but the reason for the nested selects was because a combined select (along the lines that you suggest) was not seeming to work.  But I'll look again.

Comment: I posted below, but my InnoDB Buffer Pool Size was low, and may have been part of the cause.  I'm now getting some better results.

Comment: The unusually huge pool size speeds up the nested selects in memory. You should always try to avoid nesting altogether.

Comment: Incidentally, it's breathtakingly unlikely that two tables would be joined on a column called id

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit a lot from an online tutorial on learning how to read the EXPLAIN plan.  The EXPLAINS you shared clearly show missing indexes.

As a general rule, queries should not take 23 seconds or 65 seconds, even with millions of rows.  Proper indexes + partitioning should resolve the slowness.

Query 1:  The user_id index on that table is not helping performance, as 99% of users are within the range in the where clause.  You can add an index on item_type_id

```
ALTER TABLE collections ADD KEY (item_type_id)
```

Query 2: The temp_coll table is missing a game_id index.  Also, I'm not sure if the underlying code for games_ratings_stats has an index on ratings_count and if that would help.  I dont have experience with MySQL materialized tables.

```
ALTER TABLE temp_coll ADD KEY (game_id)
```

Query 3:
Would benefit from above indexes.

Comment: Thank you - this is helpful.  I will look into ```explain```, and ```indexes```.  The item type field is only ever a 1 or a 2 - would an index help in this case, as there is little variety across the data?  Or am I misunderstanding indexes?

Comment: If it's 50% of the records, it will still help filter out 50% of the rows, but it wont be the most helpful index.  Try to think about what will give you the least rows, and query on those fields.  You can create a composite index of multiple columns to further reduce rows to more than 50% such as: ADD KEY (item_type_id, game_id)

Answer (score 1):

Your query appears to be functionally identical to the following (rather implausible) query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM ratings r
  JOIN item_stats s
    ON s.id = r.id
 WHERE r.id >= 0 
   AND r.id < 10000 
   AND r.item_type = 1 
   AND s.ratings_count > 1000
```

r.id is, presumably, the PRIMARY KEY, so it's automatically included in any INNODB index, which leaves just item_type and ratings_count requiring indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the InnoDB Buffer Pool Size (now set to 8GB) seems to have made a significant improvement.  If anyone has any further setup or tuning advice on MySQL then that would be appreciated!